# Import mysql Data in excel using Apache Poi and Spring JDBC template

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-poi, jdbctemplate

I am trying to make a utility for  importing mysql data in MS excel. I have to use Apache POI and spring MVC framework JDBC template.I searched on Google a lot for it, but I didn't get any good example for it.If anybody has did  it eyeliner kindly give me some example to do it.

I am completely on both of tools and technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POI usage is not very extensive, but still there are decent amount of resources out there. play with it and it should be fine. i have used POI and though there is some lack of documentation and usage, with some hit and trials, you should be good to go !

[POI usage tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/)

Comment: I have gone through these, but these are not helpful to me.I need it spring MVC pattern and callable from JSP. e.g. **when user want to export data into  excel it should be able to export into excel after clicking on export button**

Comment: Where is the excel file (client or server)?  Basically the JSP file is server side functionality, so unless the xls file is on the server you will have to get it there some how.  Also it is not good pratice to put code into JSP.  Think about having an action that will do the POI work.